# Simple Ajax in PHP login form not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a PHP login form where I want to add ajax code in which it helps  me to successfully login without loading windows bit during the ajax code are adding .This code is not working. Please help me fix this issue and it is possible that I dont want to show login after page in Jquery . What I mean is that after the login page i dont want `dashboard.php` to show the user. But my main issue is that my code is not working.Please help and fix my issue.

Thanks in advance.

```js
$.ajax({
 method: "POST",
 url: "loginpage.php",
 dataType: "json",
 data: { email: email, password: pass},
success:function(data)
{
if(data.type=='success')
    window.location = 'welcomepage_hideme.php';
else
//server side error from php but now
   alert("Incorrect email or and password");
}
});
```

```html
<?php
 $msg = "";

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'research_emailC', 'test123', 'research_phpEmailConfirmation');

  $email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

  if ($email == "" || $password == "")
   $msg = "Please check your inputs!";
  else {
   $sql = $con->query("SELECT id, password, isEmailConfirmed FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
   if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
                $data = $sql->fetch_array();
                if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {
                    if ($data['isEmailConfirmed'] == 0)
                     $msg = "Please verify your email!";
                    else {
                     $msg = "You have been logged in";
                      header("location: welcomepage_hideme.php");
                    }
                } else
                 $msg = "Please check your inputs!";
   } else {
    $msg = "Please check your inputs!";
   }
  }
 }
?>



<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Log In</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px;">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" align="center">

    <img src="images/logo.png"><br><br>

    <?php if ($msg != "") echo $msg . "<br><br>" ?>

    <form method="post" action="loginpage.php">
     <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email..."><br>
     <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password..."><br>
     <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
    </form>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the name of getting parameter from $_POST array:

```
$password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
```

should be:

```
$password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

Because, in the form it has **password** name:

```
<input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password..."><br>
```

Comment: I don't know how it works for now, but anyway, use are sending the key for password as "password"

Comment: I've lost me. What you mean by pastebin? And have you tried to apply changes, which I've recommended to you?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

Ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#login").submit(function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault(); 
                $.ajax({
                 method: "POST",
                 url: "login.php",
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: $(this).serialize(),
                success:function(data){ 
                    console.log(data);
                if(data.type=='success')
                    window.location = 'welcomepage_hideme.php';
                else
                //server side error from php but now
                   alert("Incorrect email or and password");
                }
                });
            });
           })
```

Html code

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" align="center">
                <form method="post" name="login_form" id="login_form">
                    <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email..."><br>
                    <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password..."><br>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: but i have checked this code in my local server after that i provided you

Comment: i have updated ajax code in my answer please try this

Comment: In "loginpage.php" in success if. Pass the response back in die(json_encode(array("type"=>"success","message"=>"login successfully")))

Answer (score 0):

The hole logic here is incorrect.

First you should move php code out from loginpage.php into fetchLogin.php:

```
<?php
$result = [ 'status' => false, 'msg' => "Please check your inputs!" ];

if ( isset( $_POST['email'] ) && isset( $_POST['password'] ) ) {
    $con = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'research_emailC', 'test123', 'research_phpEmailConfirmation' );

    $email    = $con->real_escape_string( $_POST['email'] );
    $password = $con->real_escape_string( $_POST['pass'] );

    if ( $email !== "" && $password !== "" ) {
        $sql = $con->query( "SELECT id, password, isEmailConfirmed FROM users WHERE email='$email'" );
        if ( $sql->num_rows > 0 ) {
            $data = $sql->fetch_array();
            if ( password_verify( $password, $data['password'] ) ) {
                if ( $data['isEmailConfirmed'] == 0 ) {
                    $result['msg'] = "Please verify your email!";
                } else {
                    $result['status'] = true;
                    $result['msg']    = "You have been logged in";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode( $result );

die();
```

Then update your js:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "fetchLogin.php",
  dataType: "json",
  data: { email: email, password: pass}
}).done( function( response ) {
    // code for render response.msg
    if ( ! response.status ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        setTimeout( window.location = "welcomepage_hideme.php", 3000 );
    }
});
```